# null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django. I tried to implement registration of several types of users but ran into a problem. I have two models AbstractUser and Participant. Participant is associated with OneToOnefield with AbstractUser, I wrote a serializer for them following the drf documentation, but when sending a post request, an error occurs null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint. As far as I understand, the participant model cannot communicate with AbstractUser. What could be the problem

### Models.py

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        _('phone number'),
        max_length=14,
        unique=True,
        help_text='Enter your phone number',
    )
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)


class Participant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(AbstractUser, related_name='participants', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(
        _('first name'),
        max_length=50
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        _('last name'),
        max_length=50,
    )
    device_reg_token = models.TextField(
        _('text mobile token'),
    )
    is_participant = models.BooleanField(
        _('participant status'),
        default=True
    )
```

### serializers.py

```
class AbstractUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AbstractUser
        fields = ('id', 'phone_number', 'email', 'password')


class ParticipantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    participants = AbstractUserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Participant
        fields = ('participants', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'device_reg_token')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        participants_data = validated_data.pop('participants')
        participant = Participant.objects.create_participant(
            **validated_data
        )
        for participant_data in participants_data:
            AbstractUser.objects.create_user(participant=participant, **participant_data)
        return participant
```

### views.py

```
class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Participant.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = ParticipantSerializer
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\django\MoveOn\MoveOn\MoveOnApp\views.py", line 18, in perform_create
    serializer.save(participants=self.request.user)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\django\MoveOn\MoveOn\MoveOnApp\serializers.py", line 21, in create
    participant = Participant.objects.create_participant(
  File "C:\Users\kabil\django\MoveOn\MoveOn\MoveOnApp\models.py", line 84, in create_participant
    return self._create_participant(first_name, last_name, device_reg_token,
  File "C:\Users\kabil\django\MoveOn\MoveOn\MoveOnApp\models.py", line 31, in _create_participant
    participant.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1249, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\kabil\.virtualenvs\MoveOn\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, kabiljan, Tanaguzov, gdfhjnfgdjndgfjgfj, t).
```

Comment: As the error says, what value should be used for `user`?

Comment: User cannot be null, you must pass a user object for the user field in the model and also it is a one to one primary field so your user_id will act as id(pk) for the object of this model

Answer (score 0):

base on how you did `OneToOneField` with `AbstractUser` model in `Participant`, you should have created `AbstractUser` first and `Participant` after.

The correct way to do it is:

**models.py**

```py
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        _('phone number'),
        max_length=14,
        unique=True,
        help_text='Enter your phone number',
    )
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    # fields that removed from Participant model
    is_participant = models.BooleanField(_('participant status'),default=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=50)
    device_reg_token = models.TextField( _('text mobile token'))


class Participant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(AbstractUser, related_name='participants', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class AbstractUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AbstractUser
        fields = ('id', 'phone_number', 'email', 'password', 
                 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_participant', 'device_reg_token', 'created')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        is_participant = validated_data.pop('is_participant', False)

        if is_participant:
            Participant.objects.create(user=user)   


class ParticipantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Participant
        fields = ('id', 'user')
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['user'] = AbstractUserSerializer(instance.user).data
        return rep
```

Override **create** method in `AbstractUserSerializer` and **to_representation** in `ParticipantSerializer`. Now whenever you created `User` the `Participant` will be created automatically and also you can access any field in `User` model from `Participant` model.